# Representing 1/60 chance over 1,000 or 10,000 years?

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have a an annual probability of $4.6 \times 10^{-4}$ and I'm evaluating that over a span of $35$ years can I multiply them together and get the probability of the event occurring with the $35$ year span?

If yes, it equals about $1/60$ chance (or $1.6$% chance).  How can I represent that chance occurring per $1,000$ or $10,000$ years?

Comment: Are you looking for the chance of it happening *exactly* once or *at least* once?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange, M.SE. This short guide will help you to master the MathJax needed to typeset your equations.

Comment: It's not quite correct, because it could happen on two or more years. But, because $35\cdot 4.6\times 10^{-4}$ is still a small probability, that calculation gives a relatively good approximation. Hopefully you see that you cannot use it for ten thousand years. That simplistic method would give a result of $4.6$ or 460 per cent, which is absurd. The true formula is in Bram's answer (+1).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks!  I wondered why it was so close ... I thought it was a fluke at first, but yes, it makes perfect sense with such a small chance and a limited number of years :)

Comment: Basically, by taking the two leading terms from the binomial formula, $$1-(1-p)^n\approx 1-(1-np)=np,$$ if $np$ is much smaller than $1$. The next term from the binomial formula would be $-\binom n2 p^2\approx -(np)^2/2$. But this is small in comparison to $np$ under the circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

No.  Multiplying the probability by 35 assumes that the occurrence of the event taking place one year is *mutually exclusive* from the event happening any other year, and that is not the case: the event may happen during multiple years. I wrote a [long post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356789/what-is-the-chance-of-picking-y-in-a-set-of-x-objects-given-x-chances-to-pick-a/2356879#2356879) just yesterday where I explain why the way you think about this is not correct, and how you should think about this.

Now, if you want to know the chance of the event happening at least once during the 35 year span, then first calculate the chance of it never happening, which is $(1-0.00046)^{35}$, and then subtract that from $1$, since the chance of it happening at least once is 1 minus the chance of it never happening.

[WolframAlpha's answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-(1-0.00046)%5E35) to this is about $0.0160$ or $1.60$%.  Now, this is almost the same as what you tried to do, which is $35*0.00046=0.0161$, i.e. $1,61$%, but again, your calculation is not correct. It is, as @JyrkiLahtonen points out, *close* to the correct percentage, because it happening in multiple years is (at least for 35 years) very small, but as you can see, the actual probability of about $1.60$% is a little below the $1.61$% that you get. And as you get more years, these two values will diverge more and more.

Indeed, one immediate way to tell that something is wrong with your approach is that if you move to 10,000 years, the probability would be $10000*0.00046=4.6$, i.e. $460$%! ... which is of course impossible.

The probability of it happening at least once during 1,000 years is $1-(1-0.00046)^{1000}\approx 0.369$, i.e. about $36.9$% (notice that this is **not** the same as and indeed significantly lower than $1000*0.00046=0.46$, i.e. $46$%)

For 10,000 years it is $1-(1-0.00046)^{10000}\approx 0.990$, i.e. about $99.0$% (and so certainly not $460$%!)